# How is the state managed for CDC in Azure Cosmos DB analytical store?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline

I'm currently developing a POC dataflow to investigate the capabilities of [change data capture in the analytical store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/get-started-change-data-capture) (simple pipeline with a dataflow with a CosmosDB analytical store source and a Parquet sink)

It seems that successive runs of the pipeline just pick up the changes since the last run.

In general this is of course the behaviour I want but where is this state stored and how can I reset it?

During development it is useful for me to be able to re-run the pipeline and experiment with different sinks without needing to make additional changes to the underlying cosmos data and when in production I imagine there may occasionally be cases where pipelines will need to be run and re-process some data.

I was anticipating that I might see a "Checkpoint Key" property in the dataflow settings similar to this [SAP CDC example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-change-data-capture#transform-data-with-the-sap-cdc-connector) but I see no such option.